# How to control the size of a TextBlock so the contents are fully displayed

Tags: wpf, textblock, stretch

in WPF is there a way to setup a TextBlock so its MinHeiht and MinWidth are automatically set so its content is completely visible or should I code this by myself?

Thanks.

EDIT: The TextBlock lives inside a grid row, I would like to setup the Min sizes of the row to allow the TextBlock to show its entire content.

Comment: That'll depend on the container the TextBlock lives in. If it's just in a vertical StackPanel, for instance, it'll grow horizontally to accommodate its text.

Comment: Could you please provide an example where the TextBlock lives in?

Comment: Ok, so is there a way so setup the Min sizes of the container so the contents of the TextBlock are completely visible?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the columndefinition width for the textblock's column to 'Auto', it will grow automatically to accommodate the growing textblock.

Comment: If I set the column to Auto and someone resize the form to an smaller size the textblock will be smaller and the content won't fit on it. I need a way to specify that the content of the textblock should be visible always avoiding the user to resize the form in a way that prevents the contents to be seen.

Comment: That happens because GridSplitter cannot work with Auto sized columns.  What you need to do is ensure that the GridSplitter does not act on the Auto sized column (so just add another column between the two, with a MinWidth set, and Width set to *).  This way the splitter will never touch your auto sized column.